what type of Garlic is best for the east coast area(New Jersey)
what type of garlic is good east coast (New Jersey)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi Ron, best for what?  I might assume for cooking but please also tell us what area you have to grow garlic.  Outdoors in full sun in good soil? Or???

If you have neighbors that grow garlic successfully, that's a great place to start. If you don't exactly have neighbors that grow, try the farmer's markets with somewhat local farms.
If not, I'll suggest a small number of many varieties and see what does best for you, in your soil, where you are. And/or which you prefer at the eating end of that process, since if it grows well but you don't like it, there's not  a lot of point.
I, personally, have gravitated to hardneck (only) garlics, because they appeared to do better for me where I live. That's a couple hundred miles North and a bit East of you. That does not mean the same will hold for you where you live. I set aside the largest bulbs, break them up and plant the large cloves from those largest bulbs (eating the smaller cloves) and my garlic crop stays good or gets gradually better from the selection process to favor local conditions.
My experiments have also supported scaping the garlic for bigger bulbs (and I like to eat those, so it's win/win) and providing it with considerable space. I plant on a 9x9" grid or wider. 6x6" was clearly inferior. I don't do rows, I do beds. Fall or even winter planting has beaten spring planting in all cases I've trialed. Fall is preferred, but if it gets missed, some day it's warm enough to get it in the ground in winter is better than waiting for spring.
I honestly couldn't say what exact varieties my present crop is. I got some from a friend, I bought some "Music," I bought some "Spanish Roja" and I've failed to keep them sufficiently sorted (and they are not obviously different enough to identify visually) to say what's done the best of those. I just keep whichever ones do well. I did grow some softneck for a while and it gradually shrunk to the point of being obviously not as well suited to conditions here. Rather than get new seed for it, I just stuck with more of what works here.

Yes, it's all about location, location, location. I like Russian Giant for things like goulash because it has a much different (IMO) flavor than other hardnecks, but my Giants are fast becoming non-giant (and the number of cloves per bulbs is down 50% this year) even though I do as you do and select for larger cloves. I suspect this is due to warmer winters and warmer springs than we used to have where I live. OTOH, one of my "porcelain" varieties has gotten very large over the same time period that the Giants have shrunk, probably for the same reason.
